# Is there a way to bulk extract .WTV programme-descriptions, from TV and radio files, into a spreadsheet

Tags: windows, video-recording

I record quite a lot of radio and TV programmes off Windows Media Center and, using Karen's Powertools Directory Printer list them, off Win Explorer, via a .txt file into a spreadsheet by filename.

Many of the programmes have the same title but usually their own programme description. Karen's Directory Printer extracts many programme details, but not the programme description

Ideally, I would like to be able to select a stack of filenames in Windows Explorer and have the programme descriptions copied, via the usual .TXT file, into a spreadsheet as one line of text.

I've already tried contacting 'Joe Winett' joe@karenware.com but received no reply

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: This don't seems to be asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, but any program that would let me extract the programme description from .WTV files would do, but also possibly an update to Karen's Directory Printer.                
 [PS FYI, in better English it would be "This doesn't seem to... "  (two changes)]